# Can't authenticate to use Firebase API-s on Android with React-Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm getting an error when authenticating with `firebase`. See the following error present in the `Metro` console window:

> ERROR  [Error: Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.]

This happens upon running `react-native run-android` in my `React-Native` project. The app itself runs just fine, and I can use all functionality when running the web version of the project (thanks to `react-native-web`).

I configure `firebase` in a simple config file:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
import '@firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export {firebase};
```

and import the exported `firebase` object in various places of my code. As you can see, the config is loaded from a `.env` file. If the values provided in it are for the web app, I can talk with the API-s just fine. However, if I provide config for Android, I keep getting the error mentioned before. I am completely clueless on why this happens.

I have tried various combinations of the config (including no config at all), but couldn't quite succeed. I have `google-services.json` file in the `android/app` directory, and I believe I have all required dependencies and other configuration bits properly added to the android `gradle` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible cause to this could be due to `firebaseConfig` relying on `process.env`. As stated in the node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env): `process.env` "...returns an object containing the user environment". When running your app on android this environment won't be available since it is not node.js running your application. I would recommend looking into [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv) to use environmental variables in a reliable way.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm dumb! This has fixed it, thanks! I've also had to fix the imports to use `@react-native-firebase` but it was trivial to see once I've gotten through this API key nonsense. And I was so sure I checked the env was loaded on mobile too; must've done something wrong...